# Sending email issue VB.net

Tags: vb.net

I have command line app that send an email and the issue is when i open the console and type all parameters (`SendEmail.exe` recipient subject message Sender Senderpass) email goes through OK, but when I do that from other application

```
Dim p As New ProcessStartInfo
Dim Tsubject As String = "TEST "
p.FileName = "SendEmail.exe"

p.Arguments = EmailReceivers & " " & subject & " " & " Message " & EmailSender & " " &  SenderPass
p.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal
Process.Start(p)
```

Then I get no error from `SendEmail.exe` it says `Email Successfully Sent` but I don't receive anything.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the character encoding messes around. Especially the "@" character might get messed up. Writing a batch application echo your argument will show you, if you can exclude this.

Do u have enclosed the subject in quotes? Otherwise a space might mess up the arguments.

Comment: I tried everything same results, here is what i am trying to do
I write Home Alarm App when the door/window sensor get triggered app send the alert/email to my phone, when i call it from Button then email will be sent OK but when i try call it from other SUB or FUNCTION then will not work, no error, even i get respond from the function that i call  "Alert Successfully Sent"

Answer (score -2):

Because you attach an executable file(.exe) in your email, so the target email server may filter your mail as mailware or sth dangerous and can harm the receiver.

Comment: No, OP does nothing of the sort.

Comment: I send only text message to my phone here is the code that i use in my app

Comment: OK i found the problem, the subject was too long 

Thanks Guys